# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.navigator.userAgent.match) in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I downloaded this Time picker form [react-times -npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-times) (source code from [github](https://github.com/ecmadao/react-times))

when I run the app I get the syntax error **"Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'global.navigator.userAgent.match)"** 
I can't find out what's wrong

> **Package**
>
> ```
> npm install react react-dom moment moment-timezone --save-dev
>
> npm install react-times --save-dev
> ```
>
> **Config**

```
$ npm i json-loader --save
```

[**Source Code:**](https://github.com/ecmadao/react-times/blob/master/examples/TimePickerWrapper.js)

```
import React from 'react';
import TimePicker from './src/components/TimePicker';
import timeHelper from './src/utils/time';
import ICONS from './src/utils/icons';

class TimePickerWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { defaultTime, meridiem, focused, showTimezone, timezone } = props;
    let hour = '';
    let minute = '';
    if (!defaultTime) {
      [hour, minute] = timeHelper.current().split(/:/);
    } else {
      [hour, minute] = defaultTime.split(/:/);
    }

    this.state = {
      hour,
      minute,
      meridiem,
      focused,
      timezone,
      showTimezone,
    };

    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this);
    this.onTimeChange = this.onTimeChange.bind(this);
    this.handleFocusedChange = this.handleFocusedChange.bind(this);
  }

  onTimeChange(options) {
    const {
      hour,
      minute,
      meridiem
    } = options;

    this.setState({ hour, minute, meridiem });
  }

  onFocusChange(focused) {
    console.log(`onFocusChange: ${focused}`);
    this.setState({ focused });
  }

  handleFocusedChange() {
    const { focused } = this.state;
    this.setState({ focused: !focused });
  }

  get basicTrigger() {
    const { hour, minute } = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleFocusedChange}
        className="time_picker_trigger"
      >
        <div>
          Click to open panel<br />
          {hour}:{minute}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  get customTrigger() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleFocusedChange}
        className="time_picker_trigger"
      >
        {ICONS.time}
      </div>
    );
  }

  get trigger() {
    const { customTriggerId } = this.props;
    const triggers = {
      0: (<div />),
      1: this.basicTrigger,
      2: this.customTrigger
    };
    return triggers[customTriggerId] || null;
  }

  render() {
    const {
      hour,
      minute,
      focused,
      meridiem,
      timezone,
      showTimezone,
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="time_picker_wrapper">
        <TimePicker
          trigger={this.trigger}
          {...this.props}
          focused={focused}
          meridiem={meridiem}
          timezone={timezone}
          onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
          onTimeChange={this.onTimeChange}
          showTimezone={showTimezone}
          time={hour && minute ? `${hour}:${minute}` : null}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

TimePickerWrapper.defaultProps = {
  customTriggerId: null,
  defaultTime: null,
  focused: false,
  meridiem: null,
  showTimezone: false
};

export default TimePickerWrapper;
```

**Error**
[image]

The app builds without issues but I get the above syntax error in the emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package you have chosen is only for React (web) not React Native. You should consider using [`react-native-modal-datetime-picker`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker) which is pretty good for what you need:

[image]

Check out the simple snack: https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/date-time-picker

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from 'react-native-modal-datetime-picker';

export default () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');
  const [isVisible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>{date}</Text>
      <Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={() => setVisible(true)} />
      <DateTimePicker
        mode="time"
        isVisible={isVisible}
        onConfirm={date => {
          setDate(date.toTimeString());
          setVisible(false);
        }}
        onCancel={() => setVisible(false)}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Abraham Hernandez I love this time picker